# Looking for magnifier feature in react native mobile application

Tags: android, ios, react-native, magnifier.js, android-magnifier

I'm currently working on a React Native project and I need to implement a `magnifier` `functionality`. The goal is to allow users to zoom in on specific parts of an image or interface by tapping or dragging. However, I couldn't find a suitable library for this in React Native.

I'm wondering if anyone has experience implementing such a feature or has any guidance on how to approach this. Here's what I've tried so far:

I've explored the available third-party libraries, but none seem to provide the exact functionality I need.
I've looked into using `react-native-gesture-handler` for handling gestures, but I'm not sure how to create the magnification effect.
I'm primarily targeting iOS and Android platforms. If you have any insights, code examples, or suggestions on libraries or techniques that could help me achieve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Example the feature which I want: https://app.screencast.com/qtsbTCZOf18Ew?conversation=7GDJssHzrqPNyMCwtESRJm

Any suggestion on covert react js library to react native helps because react js has a library for the same and react native doesn't

Thanks

[Demo](https://app.screencast.com/qtsbTCZOf18Ew?conversation=7GDJssHzrqPNyMCwtESRJm)